# Changing lowest level in dependency chain

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

In my project I have 5 classes:

- *ClassA* (implements interface *IClassA*), takes *IClassC* as constructor's argument
- *ClassB* (implements interface *IClassB*), takes  *IClassC* as constructor's argument
- *ClassC* (implements interface *IClassC*), takes *IClassD* as constructor's argument
- *ClassD1* and *ClassD2* (both implements interface *IClassD*)

Configuration of my Unity Container looks as follows:

```
    container.RegisterType<IClassA, ClassA>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IClassB, ClassB>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IClassC, ClassC>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IClassD, ClassD1>(nameof(ClassD1), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IClassD, ClassD2>(nameof(ClassD2), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

I would like to configure my project, that:

- *IClassA* is using *ClassC* which is using *ClassD1*
- *IClassB* is using *ClassC* which is using *ClassD2*

I'm guesing that I should change something in registration of *IClassA* and *IClassB*. I would like to avoid to change *IClassC* registration.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason why you want to do this but it is possible with the help of a factory.

Although it works, I would potentially review the design and the circumstances because it is complex and it confuses developers (it smells).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IClassC, ClassC>();
        container.RegisterType<IClassD, ClassD1>(nameof(ClassD1), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IClassD, ClassD2>(nameof(ClassD2), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IClassA, ClassA>(new InjectionConstructor(Factory.GetClassC<ClassD1>(container)));
        container.RegisterType<IClassB, ClassB>(new InjectionConstructor(Factory.GetClassC<ClassD2>(container)));

        var classA = container.Resolve<IClassA>();
        var classB = container.Resolve<IClassB>();

        classA.HelloFromA();
        classB.HelloFromB();
    }
}

public class Factory
{
    public static IClassC GetClassC<TClassD>(IUnityContainer container)
        where TClassD : IClassD
    {
        return container.Resolve<IClassC>(new DependencyOverride<IClassD>(
            container.Resolve<IClassD>(typeof(TClassD).Name)));
    }
}

public interface IClassA
{
    void HelloFromA();
}

public interface IClassB
{
    void HelloFromB();
}

public interface IClassC
{
    void HelloFromC();
}

public interface IClassD { }

public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    private readonly IClassC _classC;
    public ClassA(IClassC classC)
    {
        _classC = classC;
    }
    public void HelloFromA()
    {
        _classC.HelloFromC();
    }
}

public class ClassB : IClassB
{
    private readonly IClassC _classC;
    public ClassB(IClassC classC)
    {
        _classC = classC;
    }

    public void HelloFromB()
    {
        _classC.HelloFromC();
    }
}

public class ClassC : IClassC
{
    private readonly IClassD _classD;
    public ClassC(IClassD classD)
    {
        _classD = classD;
    }

    public void HelloFromC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello with {0}", _classD.GetType().Name));
    }
}

public class ClassD1 : IClassD
{
}

public class ClassD2 : IClassD
{
}
```

Things to note:

1. Notice the order of registration. ClassA and ClassB are registered at the end,
2. HierarchicalLifetimeManager cannot be used in this instance as you need 2 different instances of the same class.

Consider reading this article:
http://sharpfellows.com/post/Unity-IoC-Container-